# Wrap text in a Vue component dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

### Problem

I want to wrap some plain text in a Vue component dynamically, using mouseUp after selecting the text.

For example: `<div> Hello World! </div>` =>  `<div> <Greeting/> World! </div>`

### Aprox solution

Right now, I'm wrapping it using `document.createElement("span")` and surrounding the range of the selection with it.

I have found similar questions like the next one, but I'm trying to avoid render level:

[How can I dynamically wrap a substring with a component in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430943/how-can-i-dynamically-wrap-a-substring-with-a-component-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to solve it. *(Before submitting, I spend a lot of time figuring out. I don't know how I solved it so fast)*

### Solution

```
 var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Annotation);
            var instance = new ComponentClass();
            instance.$mount();
            this.range.deleteContents();
            this.range.insertNode(instance.$el);
```

**Where:** Annotation is a Vue component and the Range is the selection range obtained previously.

I hope this help someone else!

Comment: Well, if you solved it, you might as well accept your own answer.

Comment: @Ken Kinder I have to wait till tomorrow haha